# Java application freezes very frequently

Tags: java, freeze

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Xeon E5-1650 and 32 GB of RAM. For some reason, this system is having a lot of trouble running Java applications such as Eclipse and RubyMine. What happens is that within seconds of starting the application, it would simple freeze up. The only actions available are resizing the window, and the only way to kill the process is to `kill -9`.

The freezing sometimes also randomly interferes with the rest of the OS, such as preventing other (non-Java) applications from creating new windows or preventing text input in other applications, until the process is killed. Sometimes it actually freezes the entire X session and I have to `kill -9` from another tty.

I have tried multiple distributions and versions of JRE and JDK and it didn't help. The only consistent thing I've found is that this never happens on a cold boot, so a painful workaround for me is to turn off my computer for a few minutes and turn it back on.

I think this is a hardware issue, but how do I even begin to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Oracle JDK if you're using OpenJDK. I recall there was a performance difference in the Oracle JDK and the OpenJDK. I was running into performance issues in using IntelliJ, mostly being slower. That was over a year ago, not sure if the issue has been fixed today.

Comment: Yeah I've tried Oracle JDK, both 1.7 and 1.8 and multiple updates to boot. So far I know the issue is not with the JRE itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a 5960x running Ubuntu 15.10, stock Kernel 4.2.0-18, latest JDK 1.8.0_74, I'm can confirm the the cold boot fix works with the stock kernel.

The problem is also resolved using the very latest kernel 4.5.0-rc5 from mainline PPA

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/